# append non-numeric characters onto a date, but retain the ability to drag formula across

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hoping someone can help me, perhaps my problem is best described with an example.

In cell D5, I have the year 2010.

I wish to append the following to that date - '/xA' where x= the last two digits of the current cell +1. In this case, making 2010/11A.

I would then like the ability to drag this across the row, so the next cell would be 2011/12A and the next 2012/13A and so on.

If 2010 was located in cell D1, in cell E1 I would use the formula D1+1 to get 2011. In cell C1, I would use D1-1 to get 2009. I would like to do something similar, but for the above example.

I have tried playing with custom formatting and the use of the &, (i.e. =2011 & "/" & right(D5+2,2)), but the placement of the "/" gives an error when dragging across.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **D5** enter:

```
=2010+COLUMNS($A:A)-1&"/"&COLUMNS($A:A)+10&"A"
```

and copy across.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Say in **D5** we simply enter the value **2010**
Then in **E5** enter this formula:

```
=$D$5+COLUMNS($A:A)-1&"/"&COLUMNS($A:A)+10&"A"
```

and copy **E5** across:

[image: nextttt]

Comment: Excellent, thanks. However do you see anyway of avoiding hardcoding the 2010 into the formula? For example, If I typed 1999 into D5, then D6 onwards should update accordingly (D6 would be 2000/01A and so on). In D5 I can set the formatting to add the ''/00A". D5 is basically the cell that serves as the base date for the rest of the row.